# How do I list the files installed by a deb package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm an Ubuntu user and I install packages with the apt-get. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20
```

After I install the package, there will be files in /usr/bin, /usr/lib/hadoop etc. Are there any commands can show out where exactly the package installed its files?

Comment: Try the man pages of the apt command family. For example: man apt-get

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, use the `dpkg` command like

```
dpkg -L hadoop-0.20
```

The converse question (finding the package providing a given file) is answered with e.g.

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/gc/gc.h
```

Read more about Debian [packaging related tools](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html).

P.S. Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions, e.g  Mint) is a derivative of [Debian](http://debian.org/).

Comment: `dpkg` will not tell you about config files and/or files created by the postinst script if the package. If you need to be really sure you get all files if a package, you will also need to examine its packaging scripts.

Comment: if you are using a `.deb` as a reference, remember to stop right before `_`, for example ...  `hadoop-0.20_whatever.deb` would be found only as `hadoop-0.20`

Answer (score 3):

What files are installed on your system varies from package to package. To be 100% sure you should take a look into the `.deb` package yourself. Download the package first.

First you need to extract the `.deb` archive:

```
ar vx mypackage.deb
```

Now this should result in three new files: `debian-binary`, `control.tar.gz` and `data.tar.gz`. You're interested in the last one.

Now you can extract it as well using `tar`:

```
tar xzvf data.tar.gz
```

Now you can browse the package content freely. Look for any makefiles, install scripts and such like to see where things gets installed.

Comment: Just a nitpick: `tar xvf` should be enough since tar can auto-detect the format of the archive.

Answer (score 2):

You can list the installed files for a package by passing the --listfile flag to dpkg. For example, if your package is actually named "hadoop-0.20" then:

```
dpkg --listfiles hadoop-0.20
```

Comment: Or in a shorter form `dpkg -L` as I already answered.